# Retrieve optional query variables with gorilla mux?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm writing a handler that can take either POST or GET. As such, I want the option of being able to say:

```
http://host/query?parm1=value&parm2=value
```

I was assuming that Gorilla mux would then give me:

```
{
    "parm1": "value",
    "parm2": "value
}
```

but `mux.Vars(r)` is empty. I'm aware that using `.Query("key", "value"` will make the parameters mandatory, which isn't what I want. What am I missing?

Comment: `mux.Vars` is for named parameters from your route.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some provision for handling optional parameters?

Comment: `r.URL.Query().Get("param1")`?

Comment: Ah. Of course. So the basic answer is, that's not what mux is for; use the standard way of dealing with query variables.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester maybe add this as an answer?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As reflected in a comment, the basic answer is "that's not what mux is for". `mux` is great at picking apart the *path* portion of a URL, and turning the components into variables. To give a hypothetical example, a call that gives information about a country might have a spec that looks like this:

```
country/{code}
```

and accept calls that look like this:

```
http://myhost/country/DE
```

You'd get the value of the `code` parameter like this:

```
code := mux.Vars(r)["code"]
```

If you want to pass query variables, you don't do that with mux. Just grab them straight from the request. So given the alternative query syntax:

```
http://myhost/country?code=DE
```

you'd do:

```
code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")
```

Answer (score -3):

If you have an Handler function like the following, Then you can extract the Query string value (here its {param1}) using any of the two methods.

Method 1. It iterates through the query strings and prints the key and value.

Method 2. Directly extract the value using the mux Router object.

// Rounter for handling the request, Query string passed in {param1} variable

```
router.HandleFunc("/viewdemo/{param1}", GetDemoDetail).Methods("GET")


func GetData(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
// iterate throguth the object and extract key and value
    for k, v := range mux.Vars(request) {
        fmt.Printf("key=%v, value=%v", k, v)
    }

//Use the mux router to extract the value of query string {param1}
    params := mux.Vars(request)
    objid := params["param1"]
    fmt.Println("Query string key value", objid)
}
```

Comment: The question is about query string and not path params