# Gorilla Mux Router GET URL with multiple query param only matches if called by all query params

Tags: go, mux

Below is a snapshot of a HTTP Get Call while using Gorilla Mux Router:

```
usersAPIs.HandleFunc("/users",
    middleware.WrapperHandler(th.List)).
    Queries("email", "{email}").
    Queries("order_by", "{order_by}").
    Queries("order_type", "{order_type}").
    Queries("page", "{page}").
    Queries("limit", "{limit}").
    Methods("GET")
```

Now when GET call happens with all query params e.g.

```
http://localhost:xxxx/accounts/users?email=a&page=1&limit=4&order_by=a&order_type=b
```

then the gorilla mux router matches the pattern and takes it to the handler.

But when called like with fewer parameters e.g.

```
http://localhost:xxxx/accounts/users?email=a&page=1
```

then it says e.g. 404 not found means Resource path not mapped.

Questions :

#1. What has been missed here, is Go Gorilla Mux Router need all query params?

#2. What to be done If the GET query can come with zero or more parameters? e.g.

```
http://localhost:xxxx/accounts/users?email=a&page=1
```

or

```
http://localhost:xxxx/accounts/users?page=1
```

Comment: You're misusing [`Queries`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Queries), which is for adding matchers, it's not supposed to be used to just "pre-declare" query variables that you can then retrieve at your convenience. A matcher either matches or it doesn't. If doesn't the handler won't get invoked. What you should do is register a matcher only for the path and method and include only those query params that are *required* by the handler.

Comment: ... i.e. #1 Yes. #2 Remove every single `Queries` invocation from that code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @mkriva, I will look into it ,

Comment: My question was one of the version of this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045756/retrieve-optional-query-variables-with-gorilla-mux

#1, Yes , Mux works that way, 

#2. In the http request handler : To Get Optional params from RequestURI, following worked for me : e.g. Email := r.URL.Query().Get("email")

Answer (score 1):

Queries(key, value) acts as a path matcher when passed to the route. Since 5 path params are expected, the route would match only if all 5 of them are present.

Though it's a little late to answer this question, but for anyone who stubles upon it later.